# Group chunks of data of antd table

Tags: reactjs, typescript, antd

I tried to find a solution for this particular problem, but so far I've come up empty. I want to be able to group the data in my table by a specific field in my data, but I want to be able to do it as shown in the image below.
[image]

As far as I have researched, antd table doesn't offer this specific functionality or anywhere close to help me getting the below format. I've also considered creating a dataless table for the header and several tables for each data group, but then I don't know if I would be able to sync each column width other than assigning fixed values to them in addition to being able to style each header accordingly, which I would rather avoid. Grouping table head doesn't seem to be a solution here either.

Basically, is there any way I can insert a custom row in my antd table that I can design as I want?

Comment: I am also using AntD and will have to solve a similar problem. You could try just grouping/chunking the data yourself, then manually creating a table for each chunk. In other words, do the grouping/chunking outside of AntD's scope.

Comment: @DominicBou-Samra Yes, that's actually what I was going to do and it works well. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the end, I settled with splitting the data into chunks and creating a table for each chunk. The only downside of this is not having only one header for all the tables as above, but `showHeader={false}` can be passed to the antd tables for a cleaner look.